# Unable to pass values from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Header from './components/header'
import './css/main.css'

const App = ()=>{
  const [color, setColor] = useState('red');
  const fun = (color)=>{
    console.log(color)
    setColor(color)
  }
  return(<Header colorMethod={fun} color={"slategrey"}/>);
}

export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = (props)=>{
    const myStyle = {
    header:{
        background : 'lightslategrey',
        padding: "10px",
        fontFamily: "Sans-Serif",
        display:'grid',
        gridGap:'20px'
    },
    button:{
        background :'slateblue',
        color :'whitesmoke'
    }
  };
    return(
    <header style={myStyle.header}>
        This is a {props.name} and it is generally the {props.color} component that we see.
        <button style={myStyle.button} onClick={()=>{
            props.colorMethod(props.color)
        }}>Change</button>
    </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

When I click the button in the header, I get the console log however, the color is not changed.I need to build something where the props are exchanged between multiple componets.

Comment: when are you using the color?

Answer (score 1):

The color don't change because you're passing `slategrey` as props to `Header`. If you want `Header` to always have the latest color state you should pass `Header color={color} ... />`

Comment: Anyway, it won't work yet.

Comment: Agreed, but it answers the question. OP will still have to use it in its style

Comment: So can anyone suggest me how to use a state that will not change throught the application?

Comment: If your color never change don't use a state. If you want your header `slategrey` just use this hardcoded string. You can use a state if you render header multiple times with different colors.